# travel distance table design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have to develop a table that would contain distance between destinations and need some assistance for that. I am right now almost blank on how to start

[image]

here the table show distance from point `A to A, B, C AND D ARE 0, 4, 8, AND 12` respectively and so on.

need to transform this data in MySQL table to be managed by admin panel and used at client site depending on from and to destination.

Regards

Comment: no, its part of a project assigned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you don't have "real" date (like geolocation) you will need to store the data in 2 tables.

First table, locations (so store A,B,C,D there, and other relevant information about the location)

Second table, 3 columns. from_location, to_location, distance. (with a key on from/to_location so it is unique. But always check for the other way around before inserting, as you can support A,C and C,A in your table)

This way you can easily extract the correct data from the database.

For example, getting the distance from A to C (`SELECT distance FROM distance_table WHERE from_location = "A" AND to_location = "C"`)

Comment: thanks for the advice, can you please check [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b806f/2) I just generated. Is this required to insert values both way? performance wise

Comment: and what about admin? what interface would be presented in this design to the admin? if he needs to insert or update some records ie adding new locations or modifying existing?

Comment: that is a whole different question. Plus, this site is not a code request site. Please try first. If you don't know how to do it, ask a different question for it, and show what you have tried ;)

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need a table that has 3 columns. Point A, Point B, distance

In your program, you can do 2 for loop to get through the 2 dimension table as inserts.

If you want it to be unique, then in your code, you make want to try if you currently looking at B to A, check if A to B already exist before inserting again. Might be wise to also place some constraint on the table where PointA and PointB Must be unique

Answer (score 0):

Make a table

```
Create table `table_name`( `Distance_from` varchar(2), `A` int,`B` int, `C` int, `D` int ,primary key(Distance_from));
```

Then insert your record like

```
Insert into `table_name`(`Distance_from`,`A`,`B`,`C`,`D`) values('A',0,4,8,12)
```

similarly insert all your rows.

Comment: bro this was sample data, I have loads of locations to fill.. this structure will not work in any way

Comment: @Junaid  then you can use a table where latitude and  longitude of every sation is placed in same row and then use formula to calculate distance between two station